# Need help with taylor polynomial of n-th degree

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Lets assume that we calculate Taylor polynomial of $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ degree around the point $a=0$ for the function $\sin(x)$. How do I find the smallest value of $n$ that I can use so that the residual $R_{n}f(x) \leq 0.01, \, \forall x \in [0,1/3]$? And what is that value as well?

Comment: There are certain estimates of the said residual. I vaguely recall that they have to do with the (n+1)'th derivative. Rings a bell?

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean could you explain further

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
is an alternating series, therefore the error is less than the absolute value of the first term neglected. In other words you should find $n$ such that
$$\frac{\left(\frac13\right)^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}\le 0.01$$
we get that $n=2$ terms are enough to keep the error less than $0.01$. Actually with two terms we get $\sin \frac13\approx \frac{53}{162}\approx 0.32716$ with an error less than $0.0001$ which means $4$ decimal exact
$$
\begin{array}{l|r}
 n & \texttt{error}\\
\hline
 1 & 0.333333 \\
 2 & 0.00617284 \\
 3 & 0.0000342936 \\
 4 & 9.1\times 10^{-8}\\
\end{array}
$$